# Spring with AJAX integration

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

So I'm able to successfully integrate AJAX requests with Spring MVC. However, I have a problem- if I click the "submit" button of my form, my @Controller class detects the url and returns a ModelAndView. However, what I want is that there be an AJAX check first, and if the form submission is not successful (e.g., blank fields), return an AJAX response. Otherwise, proceed as per normal and display a ModelAndView. However, I have no clue how to integrate both at the same time.

Any ideas or tutorials are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you plan to handle the ajax response in the client? If its successful you get html, otherwise json. Looks not like a clean solution to me.

Comment: if not successful, return json from my method (which I know how to code). if successful, return ModelAndView object from my method (which I know how to code). the problem is how to handle both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several choices:

- submit the form to a specific, different URL, when using AJAX
- add a specific parameter to the request when posting using AJAX, and use this specific parameter to check if the request is n AJAX request
- test if the `X-Requested-With` request header is present and contains `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: thanks! suppose i go with the 1st option. how would i redirect to the other url if the ajax url is successful? the problem is that in the ajax case, i can return a @ResponseBody, but in the regular case, ive gotta return the ModelAndView object.

Comment: In your JavaScript code, instead of posting the form to the normal URL (the one in the `action` attribute of the form), you post the form using AJAX to a *different* URL, which is handled by *another* Spring method returning a ResponseBody.

Comment: How about when I want to return a ModelAndView. Basically, I want to use Ajax to submit a form, instantly display errors if there are any, and otherwise redirect.

Comment: If the AJAX method succeeds, then make your JavaScript success response handler redirect to the appropriate location.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the PJAX route or what's also known as HiJax.

Basically you return a subset of the page if it's an AJAX request using headers. Most people than just use conditions in their view/template to decide to include the full or chrome-less HTML.